# Converting array of text to drop down items?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm using Vue and vue-boostrap. I have an array of text items coming up from my database that are populated in a `<b-form-select>` (a dropdown). This bootstrap element takes in objects of the form `{value: 'some value', text: 'displayed text'}`.

My array is of the form `['item1', 'item2', 'item3']`.

Is there a more efficient way to make my array into the dropdown-friendly objects without an ugly `forEach`, constucting each new object in a new dropdown-friendly array? What I have right now is:

```
formatEventTypes() {
  this.eventTypes = [];
  this.rawEventTypes.forEach(rawType => {
    this.eventTypes.push({value: rawType, text: rawType});
  });
}
```

This works, but seeing as I have a few dropdowns, it's not the most efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.eventTypes = this.rawEventTypes && this.rawEventTypes.map(({ type }) => ({ value: type, text: type}))
```

but what i don't understand is how come your code(***rawType.type***) would work if your array is of the form

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

instead of,

```
[{ type: 'item1' }, { type: 'item2' }, { type: 'item3' }]
```

Comment: @Dan, one thing i should'v e mentioned is the useage. you can expect a return value in your case an array when using map, filter etc.., where as find returns the element of first match depends upon whether the element is an object, string etc.Array.prototype.forEach is like a substitute to our regular for loop. it won't return anything but can perform some operations on the elements. it's return value would be undefined if you tried to assign as we did in the answer that is the reason we have to declare another array and push into it. Many people use these without these kinda insight..

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function as below and reuse it multiple times.

```
//rawItems is array of string
//eg: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
function getDropdownItems(rawItems) {
  var dropdownItems = [];
  rawItems.forEach(item => {
    dropdownItems.push({value: item, text: item});
  });
  return dropdownItems;
}
```

Comment: I'm choosing Sarath's answer but just wanted to say that yours is good too